# Apache2 + wsgi + flask unable to load the homepage (or- produces "504 gateway timeout") on an Ubuntu 20.04 Azure VM

Tags: azure, apache, ubuntu, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a flask app on an Azure Ubuntu 20.04 VM (Standard E20as v5) using apache2 + wsgi.

The flask app is located at `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/` with a Python venv in `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv`. Python version is 3.9.17.

I can start the apache without any issues:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-06-26 06:49:27 UTC; 8s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1708 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SU>
   Main PID: 1712 (apache2)
      Tasks: 57 (limit: 193324)
     Memory: 29.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─1712 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1715 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─1716 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jun 26 06:49:27 ServerName systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 26 06:49:27 ServerName systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

But when typing the VM's IP in the browser, both in HTTP and HTTPS, I used to get "504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT", but now (since I extended the Timeout parameter in the apache conf file), the browser just keep trying to load the page without any message (not even after 10 minutes...).

This is the error from the error log:

```
[Mon Jun 26 07:25:00.309224 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 2989:tid 140305911248640] [client <IP>:58226] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'flaskapp': /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/app.wsgi
```

As to the VM's network, I think it is open since:

- I added two inbound port rules: one for port 80 and one for port 443, with Protocol="Any", Source="Any", Destination="Any", Action="Allow".
- Before installing my app, the apache default homepage appeared when I typed the VM's IP in the browser. (I now removed it from `/var/www/html/`)

This is the app configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/flaskapp.com.conf` (this is the only file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, I removed the default files):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName flaskapp.com
   ServerAlias www.flaskapp.com
   ServerAdmin Admin@localhost
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/"

   WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
   WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp request-timeout=600 processes=2 threads=20 user=www-data group=www-data python-home=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/ python-path=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/:/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/app.wsgi
   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

   <Directory "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/">
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-access_log combined
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-error_log
    LogLevel  warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.institution.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.institution.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/institution-ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName flaskapp.com
   ServerAlias www.flaskapp.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/"

   WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
#  WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp processes=2 threads=20 user=www-data python-home=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/ python-path=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/:/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/app.wsgi
   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

   <Directory "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/">
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-access_log combined
   ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-error_log
   LogLevel  warn
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the apache configuration file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#       /etc/apache2/
#       |-- apache2.conf
#       |       `--  ports.conf
#       |-- mods-enabled
#       |       |-- *.load
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |-- conf-enabled
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       `-- sites-enabled
#               `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 600

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

This is `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/app.wsgi`:

```
#!/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/python3.9

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool')

activate_this = '/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from main import app as application
```

And this is `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/main.py`:

```
LOTS OF CODE...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I changed the `/var/www/html/` ownership to `www-data`, so `ls -l /var/www/html/` now returns

```
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 26 06:56 FLASKAPP.web.tool
```

But it didn't help.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `python-home=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/`
to
`python-home=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv` in the app configuration file and the problem was solved. However, I then encountered another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76568937/7472669).