# Numpy error when deploying Flask app in Python 3.9 (linux): No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: linux, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a flask app on an Azure Ubuntu 20.04 VM (Standard E20as v5) using apache2 + wsgi.

The flask app is located at `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/` with a Python venv in `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv`. Python version is 3.9.17. Numpy version is 1.24.4.

When typing the VM's IP in the browser, both in HTTP and HTTPS, I get an "internal server error". This is the error from the `/var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-error_log`:

```
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:
* The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/python"
* The NumPy version is: "1.24.4"
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

The weird thing is that it says `Python3.8`. However, `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/python -V` returns `Python 3.9.17`.

This is what `ll /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/pyt*` returns:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  7 Jun 23 18:14 /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/python -> python3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 16 Jun 23 18:14 /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  7 Jun 23 18:14 /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/python3.9 -> python3*
```

and `ll /usr/bin/python*` returns:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3662032 Jul  1  2022 /usr/bin/python2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Jun 22 08:51 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5494584 May 26 14:05 /usr/bin/python3.8*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5766288 Jun  6 20:11 /usr/bin/python3.9*
```

As far as I can tell, none of the scenarios in https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html fits my case.
These are the `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH`:

```
Admin@ServerName:/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool$ source flaskapp_venv/bin/activate
(flaskapp_venv) Admin@ServerName:/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool$ python
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jun  6 2023, 20:11:04)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import os
>>> print("PYTHONPATH:", os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))
PYTHONPATH: /var/www/html/SPIRAL.web.tool/spiral_venv/bin/
>>> print("PATH:", os.environ.get('PATH'))
PATH: /var/www/html/SPIRAL.web.tool/spiral_venv/bin:/var/www/html/SPIRAL.web.tool:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>>>
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall numpy as advised in some places by that didn't help. I also completely removed flaskapp_venv and then recreated it, and then installed Numpy first (before the other packages). That also didn't help.

Some more information...

This is the app configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/flaskapp.com.conf` (this is the only file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, I removed the default files):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName flaskapp.com
   ServerAlias www.flaskapp.com
   ServerAdmin Admin@localhost
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/"

   WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
   WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp request-timeout=600 processes=2 threads=20 user=www-data group=www-data python-home=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv python-path=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/:/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/app.wsgi
   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

   <Directory "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/">
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-access_log combined
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-error_log
    LogLevel  warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.institution.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.institution.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/institution-ca-bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName flaskapp.com
   ServerAlias www.flaskapp.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/"

   WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
#  WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp processes=2 threads=20 user=www-data python-home=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/ python-path=/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/:/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/app.wsgi
   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

   <Directory "/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/">
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-access_log combined
   ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/flaskapp.com-error_log
   LogLevel  warn
</VirtualHost>
```

This is `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/app.wsgi`:

```
#!/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/python3.9

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/')

activate_this = '/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/flaskapp_venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from main import app as application
```

And this is `/var/www/html/FLASKAPP.web.tool/main.py`:

```
LOTS OF CODE...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Edit:**

I checked in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and found that `mod_wsgi` does in fact run the wrong version of Python:

```
AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I'm now trying to configure `mod_wsgi` to run Python3.9 and I would appreciate any help doing that.